What is the tension in the coupling between carraige 1 and carraige 2
This is a question from my Physics textbook.
A railway engine pulls two carriages of equal mass with uniform acceleration. The tension in the coupling between the engine and the first carriage is T
Deduce the tension in the coupling between first and second carriages.
The pulling force on either side is inequal, and so the string itself is moving, but I don't get whether I'm supposed to add the forces on either side?

Yes, you need to calculate the net force on each carriage.
If the tension in the coupling between the first and the second carriage is $T'$ then the net force on the first carriage is $T-T'$ and the net force on the second carriage is $T'$. Since the two carriages have the same mass and the same acceleration we must have
$T-T' = T'$

The sum of forces on an object (in a particular direction) is equal to the object's mass x acceleration.  This is also true for a group of objects that accelerate together.  In that case, you ignore the internal forces between the objects.
So, you know that the given tension is accelerating both carriages.  Drawing a free-body diagram of the problem statement with both carriages and summing forces horizontally results in
$$ T = (2m)a$$
The tension between the carriages is acting to accelerate the second carriage of mass $m$ with the same acceleration $a$.  So draw a free-body diagram of only the second carriage and deduce
$$T' = ma = T/2$$
You could get this result in a different way, by a free-body diagram of the first carriage.  In that case there would be a tension $T$ to the right (say) and a tension $T'$ to the left, each from a coupling.  Summing forces would give
$$T - T' = ma$$
